# Delete duplicates from TextBox, if line after = line before

Tags: c#, textbox, duplicates

I have a TextBox and want to delete lines if line before = line after.

I have Text like that:

```
Ab cd ...

Ef Gss ...
EE oo ...
EE oo ... // delete this line
qq ss ff

ok ee ..
```

I tried with many codes but it removed me all same lines. I just want to remove next same line. Empty lines should be always there.

Code I used:

```
richTextBox1.Text = string.Join( Environment.NewLine, richTextBox1.Lines.Distinct());
```

Or:

```
for (int tx = 0; tx < richTextBox1.Text.Length; tx++)
        {
            for (int tx1 = tx + 1; tx1 < richTextBox1.Text.Length; tx1++)
            {
                if (richTextBox1.Lines[tx] == richTextBox1.Lines[tx1])
                   // something like  richTextBox1.Lines[tx1].RemoveAt(tx1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: TextBox1.Text = string.Join( Environment.NewLine, richTextBox1.Lines.Distinct(l => l != string.Empty));

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: i got error: cannot convert lambda expression

Comment: I have just tested my answer with your text and works. Just replace control name

Comment: @CarlosLande: what do u mean by replace control name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
      string[] temp = richTextBox1.Lines;
      for (int i= 0; i< richTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1; i++)
      {
          if (richTextBox1.Lines[i] == richTextBox1.Lines[i+ 1]
               && rt.Lines[i] != String.Empty)
          {
              temp[i] = null;
          }
      }
      richTextBox1.Lines = temp.Where(a => a != null).ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks, and how can i delete this lines too? i mean delete and remove complete this duplicated lines?

Comment: Last line where we are `resetting the Lines property of richTextBox` will delete these lines from richTextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, textBox1.Lines.Distinct());
```

Comment: I guess this would remove "all" duplicates instead of "all nextline" duplicates

Comment: same answer as mine, please see above

Comment: Your answer is  not compiling for me. Invalid lambda expression

Comment: please see 1.code, same like mine, only changed textBox1 with RichTextBox1

Comment: You are right Uni Le I didn't read that line, just the big code. Sorry my fault! :P Glad you got correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Code you've posted looks fine for deleting next lines but you are deleting all lines in the rest of text that equals to line in first loop.
So in your code

```
xyz//line0
abc//line1
abc//line2
//line3
hjk//line4
abc//line5
```

Lines: 2,5 will be removed and if i understand correctly you want to remove only line 2.

my example

```
line1 text //line index 0
abc //line index 1
abc//delete this line, index 2
abc//delete this line, index 3
```

step1. line index 2 was deleted

```
line1 text //line index 0
abc //line index 1
//deleted abc line, previous index 2, 
abc//delete this line, index 2, previous index 3
```

but tx after removing line index 2 will be incremented so you will be at base text line 3
so we need to add tx--

```
for (int tx = 0; tx < richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1; tx++)
    {
            if (richTextBox1.Lines[tx] == richTextBox1.Lines[tx+1])
            {
               // something like  richTextBox1.Lines[tx+1].RemoveAt(tx);
               tx--;
            }
        }
    }
```

and if you don't want to remove empty lines you should modify above if statment

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBox1.Lines[tx]) &&richTextBox1.Lines[tx] == richTextBox1.Lines[tx+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the yield operator addresses this problem :

```
public static IEnumerable<String> GetDistinctLines(IEnumerable<String> lines)
{
    string currentLine = null;
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        if (line != currentLine)
        {
            currentLine = line;
            yield return currentLine;
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
richTextBox1.Lines = GetDistinctLines(richTextBox1.Lines).ToArray();
```